# Add page curl like layer (not animation)

Tags: ios, xcode, quartz-graphics, uianimation, page-curl

I want to be clear that I **do not** need help with *page curl animation*.

I am trying to find the best way to add a "page curl" image effect to the bottom of one my views. Similar to the iPad maps app.

**Here is an example:**

[image: Page curl effect]

Of course, once this area is hit, the page curls. Easy enough.

I am thinking that it would be using some Quartz to draw?

I have even thought about doing a small curl animation to get it to there but that seems a bit dirty.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just add a image file as a button in the corner to simulate a page curl?